# Need to remove value from html array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have used array to get the input values of each row in html.
The code is

```
<input type="text" name="source[]" id="source'+row'">
```

I need to remove the elements from the array when i remove the a row.

```
var source=document.getElementsByName("source");
 Array.prototype.forEach.call( source, function( node,index ) {
    if(index==id){
        node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
    }
});
```

when I console the result, the child is removed. But when I submit the form using PHP, the array has empty values.

```
`['24','','',56]`
```

How to remove the empty values.

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem but a quick fix would be to filter the array by its elements value before you send them. E.g.: source.filter(item => item); This will remove empty values.

Comment: Is var source and array? Where is id coming from? Is the only thing wrong that the source array is not correct? It would help if you posted more of your code so that we can gain context

Comment: If the input is a child node of the row, and you remove the row using removeChild or similar, it will get rid of the input automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, I fixed the issues in php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to remove empty values from an array would be:

```
var this_array = this_array.filter(function(x){
  return (x !== (undefined || null || ''));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It just works, check again what you are doing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function test(){
                var source=document.getElementsByName("source[]");
                Array.prototype.forEach.call( source, function( node,index ) {
                    if(index===1){
                        node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        var_dump($_GET);
        ?>
        <hr>
        <form action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="source[]"><br>
            <input type="text" name="source[]"><br>
            <input type="text" name="source[]"><br>
            <input type="text" name="source[]"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="sub">
        </form>
        <button onclick="test()">test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

(It is a PHP file expecting to be `index.php`, sending the array to itself, button `test` removes element with index==1)